# Tag all duplicate rows in R as in Stata

Tags: r, data.table, plyr, stata

Following up from my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22834725/1414455), I am trying to replicate in R the functionality of the Stata command `duplicates tag`, which allows me to tag all the rows of a dataset that are duplicates in terms of a given set of variables:

```
clear *
set obs 16
g f1 = _n
expand 104
bys f1: g f2 = _n
expand 2
bys f1 f2: g f3 = _n
expand 41
bys f1 f2 f3: g f4 = _n
des  // describe the dataset in memory

preserve
sample 10  // draw a 10% random sample
tempfile sampledata
save `sampledata', replace
restore

// append the duplicate rows to the data
append using `sampledata'
sort f1-f4

duplicates tag f1-f4, generate(dupvar)
browse if dupvar == 1  // check that all duplicate rows have been tagged
```

### Edit

Here is what Stata produces (added on @Arun's request):

> ```
> f1   f2   f3   f4   dupvar  
>  1    1    1    1        0  
>  1    1    1    2        0  
>  1    1    1    3        1  
>  1    1    1    3        1  
>  1    1    1    4        0  
>  1    1    1    5        0  
>  1    1    1    6        0  
>  1    1    1    7        0  
>  1    1    1    8        1  
>  1    1    1    8        1
> ```

Note that for `(f1, f2, f3, f4) = (1, 1, 1, 3)` there are two rows, and both of those are marked `dupvar = 1`. Similarly, for the two rows that are duplicates for `(f1, f2, f3, f4) =(1, 1, 1, 8)`.

### R:

The base function `duplicated` tags only the second duplicate onwards. So, I wrote a function to replicate the Stata functionality in R, using `ddply`.

```
# Values of (f1, f2, f3, f4) uniquely identify observations
dfUnique = expand.grid(f1 = factor(1:16),
            f2 = factor(1:41),
            f3 = factor(1:2),
            f4 = factor(1:104))

# sample some extra rows and rbind them
dfDup = rbind(dfUnique, dfUnique[sample(1:nrow(dfUnique), 100), ])

# dummy data 
dfDup$data = rnorm(nrow(dfDup))

# function: use ddply to tag all duplicate rows in the data
fnDupTag = function(dfX, indexVars) {
  dfDupTag = ddply(dfX, .variables = indexVars, .fun = function(x) {
    if(nrow(x) > 1) x$dup = 1 else x$dup = 0
    return(x)
  })
  return(dfDupTag)
}

# test the function
indexVars = paste0('f', 1:4, sep = '')
dfTemp = fnDupTag(dfDup, indexVars)
```

But as in the linked question, performance is a huge issue. [Another possible solution](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Identifying-duplicate-rows-td4642679.html) is

```
dfDup$dup = duplicated(dfDup[, indexVars]) | 
  duplicated(dfDup[, indexVars], fromLast = TRUE) 
dfDupSorted = with(dfDup, dfDup[order(eval(parse(text = indexVars))), ])
```

I have a few questions:
1. Is it possible to make the `ddply` version faster?
2. Is the second version using `duplicated` correct? For more than two copies of the duplicated rows?
3. How would I do this using `data.table`? Would that be faster?

Comment: @Arun I want to take no action -- I want to create an indicator that identifies homogenous groups identified by a set of variables.

Comment: @Arun Have added sample output.

Comment: you can get `dupvar` just with `ave(1:nrow(dd), dd[, 1:4], FUN = function(x) length(x) > 1)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll answer your third question here.. (I think the first question is more or less answered in your [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893290/r-aggregating-duplicate-rows-by-taking-sum/22894279#22894279)).

```
## Assuming DT is your data.table
DT[, dupvar := 1L*(.N > 1L), by=c(indexVars)]
```

`:=` adds a new column `dupvar` *by reference* (and is therefore very fast because no copies are made). `.N` is a special variable within `data.table`, that provides the number of observations that belong to each group (here, for every `f1,f2,f3,f4`).

Take your time and go through `?data.table` (and run the examples there) to understand the usage. It'll save you a lot of time later on.

So, basically, we group by `indexVars`, check if `.N > 1L` and if it's the case, it'd return `TRUE`. We multiply by `1L` to return an `integer` instead of `logical` value.

If you require, you can also sort it by the by-columns using `setkey`.

---

From the next version on (currently implemented in v1.9.3 - development version), there's also a function `setorder` that's exported that *just* sorts the `data.table` *by reference*, without setting keys. It also can sort in ascending or descending order. (Note that `setkey` *always* sorts in ascending order only).

That is, in the next version you can do:

```
setorder(DT, f1, f2, f3, f4)
## or equivalently
setorderv(DT, c("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"))
```

In addition, the usage `DT[order(...)]` is also optimised internally to use `data.table`'s fast ordering. That is, `DT[order(...)]` is detected internally and changed to `DT[forder(DT, ...)]` which is incredibly faster than base's `order`. So, if you don't want to change it by reference, and want to assign the sorted `data.table` on to another variable, you can just do:

```
DT_sorted <- DT[order(f1, f2, f3, f4)] ## internally optimised for speed
                                       ## but still copies!
```

HTH

Comment: The Stata command `duplicates tag` actually reports the number of duplicates, so the right solution is even simpler `DT[, dupvar := .N - 1L, by=c(indexVars)]`. Also [this discussion](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/924)

Answer (score 2):

I don't really have an answer to your three questions, but I can save you some time. I also split time between Stata and R and often miss Stata's `duplicates` commands. But if you `subset` then `merge` with `all=TRUE`, then you can save a lot of time.

Here's an example.

```
# my more Stata-ish approach
system.time({
    dupes <- dfDup[duplicated(dfDup[, 1:4]), 1:4]
    dupes$dup <- 1
    dfTemp2 <- merge(dfDup, dupes, all=TRUE)
    dfTemp2$dup <- ifelse(is.na(dfTemp2$dup), 0, dfTemp2$dup)
})
```

This is quite a bit faster.

```
> system.time({
+ fnDupTag = function(dfX, indexVars) {
+   dfDupTag = ddply(dfX, .variables = indexVars, .fun = function(x) {
+     if(nrow(x) > 1) x .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
 118.75    0.22  120.11 

> # my more Stata-ish approach
> system.time({
+     dupes <- dfDup[duplicated(dfDup[, 1:4]), 1:4]
+     dupes$dup <- 1
+     dfTemp2 <- merge(dfDup,  .... [TRUNCATED] 
   user  system elapsed 
   0.63    0.00    0.63
```

With identical results (subject to `all.equal`'s precision).

```
> # compare
> dfTemp <- dfTemp[with(dfTemp, order(f1, f2, f3, f4, data)), ]

> dfTemp2 <- dfTemp2[with(dfTemp2, order(f1, f2, f3, f4, data)), ]
> all.equal(dfTemp, dfTemp2)
[1] "Attributes: < Component 2: Mean relative difference: 1.529748e-05 >"
```