# Aggregating duplicate rows by taking sum

Tags: r, data.table, plyr

Following on from my questions:
1. [Identifying whether a set of variables uniquely identifies each row of the data or not;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22834725/1414455)
2. [Tagging all rows that are duplicates in terms of a given set of variables,](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893028/1414455)
I would now like to aggregate/consolidate all the duplicate rows in terms of a given set of variables, by taking their sum.

### Solution 1:

There is some guidance on how to do this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10180132/1414455), but when there are a large number of levels of the variables that form the index, the `ddply` method recommended there is slow, as it was in the case where I was trying to tag all the duplicates by a given set of variables.

```
# Values of (f1, f2, f3, f4) uniquely identify observations
dfUnique = expand.grid(f1 = factor(1:16),
                       f2 = factor(1:41),
                       f3 = factor(1:2),
                       f4 = factor(1:104))

# sample some extra rows and rbind them
dfDup = rbind(dfUnique, dfUnique[sample(1:nrow(dfUnique), 100), ])

# dummy data 
dfDup$data = rnorm(nrow(dfDup))

# aggregate the duplicate rows by taking the sum
dfDupAgg = ddply(dfDup, .(f1, f2, f3, f4), summarise, data = sum(data))
```

### Solution 2:

The second solution is to use `data.table`, and following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399304/1414455), I could do

```
# data.table solution
indexVars = paste0('f', 1:4, sep = '')
dtDup = data.table(dfDup, key = indexVars)
dtDupAgg = dtDup[, list(data = sum(data)), by = key(dtDup)]
```

I have a couple of questions:
1. Is there a way to make the `ddply` version faster?
2. Is the `data.table` correct? I want to check since I am new to `data.table`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding your `data.table` solution, you don't need to *set key* for aggregation operations. You can directly do:

```
indexVars = paste0('f', 1:4, sep = '')
dtDup <- as.data.table(dfDup) ## faster than data.table(.)
dtDupAgg = dtDup[, list(data = sum(data)), by = c(indexVars)]
```

`data.table` version 1.9.2+ also implements a function `setDT` that enables conversion of `data.frames` to `data.tables` *by reference* (which means, there is no copy and therefore takes almost no time in the conversion, especially useful on large data.frames).

So, instead of doing:

```
dtDup <- as.data.table(dfDup)
dtDup[...]
```

You could do:

```
## data.table v1.9.2+
setDT(dfDup) ## faster than as.data.table(.)
dfDup[...]   ## dfDup is now a data.table, converted by reference
```

---

On your first question, `plyr` is not known for its speed. Check [Why is plyr so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533438/why-is-plyr-so-slow) (and the many informative comments there) for more info.

Perhaps you maybe interested in `dplyr`, which is orders of magnitude faster than `plyr`, but still slower than `data.table`, IMHO. Here's the equivalent `dplyr` version:

```
dfDup %.% group_by(f1, f2, f3, f4) %.% summarise(data = sum(data))
```

---

Here's a benchmark between `data.table` and `dplyr` on the data (all timings are minimum of three consecutive runs):

```
## data.table v1.9.2+
system.time(ans1 <- dtDup[, list(data=sum(data)), by=c(indexVars)])
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.049   0.009   0.057 

## dplyr (commit ~1360 from github)
system.time(ans2 <- dfDup %.% group_by(f1, f2, f3, f4) %.% summarise(data = sum(data)))
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.374   0.013   0.389
```

I really don't have the patience to run the `plyr` version (stopped after 93 seconds of first run). As you can see `dplyr` is much faster than `plyr`, but ~7x times slower than `data.table` here.

---

Check if the results are equal to be sure:

```
all.equal(as.data.frame(ans1[order(f1,f2,f3,f4)]), 
          as.data.frame(ans2))
# [1] TRUE
```

HTH

Comment: For the `ddply` timing (2.8 GHz Core i7 16MB RAM MacBook Pro)
`system.time(dfDupAgg2 <- ddply(dfDup, .(f1, f2, f3, f4), summarise, data = sum(data)))
user [109.305] system [19.276] elapsed [128.528]` whereas the `group_by` took (on avg) ~`0.21` :-)